# JSON Extractor - Extract data - Can not be applied to primitive

Tags: java, jmeter, performance-testing

I'm using JMeter 5.1.1 and try do a load test. I added JSON Extractor for extract user context from GET Request as follows,

**Name of created variables:**

```
schoolId; 
teacherAccountId; 
teacherProfileId; 
teacherUserName; 
schoolLogoId;
```

**JSON Path Expressions :**

```
$.[?(@.type == 'SCHOOL')].id; 
$.[?(@.type == 'SCHOOL')].accountId; 
$.[?(@.type == 'SCHOOL')].profileId; 
$.[?(@.type == 'SCHOOL')].username; 
$.[?(@.type == 'SCHOOL')].icon.id;
```

When I execute 800 user threads gives the following error from client-side.

It will run a loop for all assigned variables (`teacherProfileId; teacherUserName; schoolLogoId;`)

then after gives error from server side  - `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space Dumping heap to java_pid23134.hprof` ...

What can I do for that? Is there anything wrong with JSON extractor configurations?

Note - I already increase JVM Heap size to 4G

```
 Error processing JSON content in JSON Extractor -Extract user data from user context, message: Filter: [?]['teacherAccountId'] can not be applied to primitives. Current context is: org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException: connect timed out
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:151)
        at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl$JMeterDefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(HTTPHC4Impl.java:336)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:374)

....
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't get any valid JSON as the response and looking into

> connect timed out at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect`

it looks like your application gets overloaded hence you are not receiving a proper response.

There is nothing to do with the JMeter script, you need to report the performance error. If time allows you can enhance your report to contain:

1. The maximum number of users which can access the application without any issues (consider using reasonable [ramp-up period](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-ramp-up-the-ultimate-guide/) in order to onboard these 800 users **gradually**)
2. [Saturation point](http://hd-performance.blogspot.com/2010/05/saturation-point.html) - to wit what was the maximum throughput and what was the number of users at this stage (you can check it using i.e. [`Hits/s vs Active Threads` listener](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ResponseTimesVsThreads/)
3. Did the application have enough headroom to operate in terms of CPU, Memory, etc. as the error can be caused by lack of essential resources. You can check it using [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PerfMon/)
4. Check your application logs for any suspicious entries
5. Does the application recover when the load decreases

Comment: Actually There is free 2g heap memory during the load test and CPU usage also around 15%- 20%. Seems no resource overloading.

Comment: I tried with 2 JMeter agents with balancing load. 400 Requests for one agent and 400 for another and hit both agents at once. server get loaded around 20%-22% CPU usage. Seems will further increase the load with different JMeter agents.